# PL/SQL - CASE inside WHERE with local variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, where-clause

I would like to select some records from table with WHERE clause based on the local variable - is this is a "correct" way of doing it? I know it works, but I think there should be a better way somewhere :)

So let say I have a procedure with some argument, like a p_type, now I would like to select some records from the table and if a user passed a valid p_type argument I will select only records of type specified. Otherwise I will select all records - no type check needed.

"Lame" way is to check if TYPE IS NOT NULL and do proper SELECT with or without WHERE clause. But I do it this way:

```
SELECT ID, TYPE, NAME FROM MY_TABLE t WHERE
  TYPE = 
    CASE p_type
     WHEN NULL THEN t.TYPE
     ELSE p_type
    END;
```

Is it ok to do it this way? For sure it works :)

Comment: Hi, is NVL operator not good? see documentation: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php

Comment: Or, [LNNVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions091.htm#SQLRF06327)

Comment: If it works then it fine, but its kinda trying to fill your right pocket using your left hand. There are simpler ways to do this.

Comment: Great! Could someone show me how could I use the LNNVL() with my example?

Comment: where type=nvl(p_type,t.type)

Comment: @EatÅPeach - until you mentioned it here I didn't know this function existed. Could you provide an example of using LNNVL in this situation? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LNNVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions091.htm#SQLRF06327) returns TRUE if condition is FALSE and FALSE if condition is TRUE. But most importantly, it returns TRUE if the condition is UNKNOWN.

Since, LNNVL inverts our condition, we must use inverted condition.

In this example, `type = p_type` will become, `lnnvl(type != p_type)`

```
SELECT ID, TYPE, NAME 
FROM MY_TABLE t 
WHERE LNNVL(TYPE != p_type);
```

Sample [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b1c62/1).

But, using NVL or COALESCE is straightforward in this case.

```
where type = COALESCE(p_type,type)
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. What is better:

where type=nvl(p_type,t.type) 

or

WHERE LNNVL(TYPE != p_type);  ?

First one will be most likely easier to understand to someone who will work with my code in future, I think...

Comment: @user1071076, yes first one is better.